# How to delete the specific database value

Tags: php

Below is my SQL table

```
| ID |   Value   |
| 1  | A1 A2 A3  |
```

I would like to delete the A3 in the column: *Value*. Is there any method to do this?

Comment: You can use SQL Update: `UPDATE table SET Value = 'A1 A2' Where Id = 1`

Comment: Yes three of the value are in one database record

Comment: It boils down to simple string manipulation. Select the value, remove `A3` from the string and store it back. But, overall, you should reconsider your database design. [Storing multiple values in one column is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Comment: Ok, Thank You for giving the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to edit/remove part of string, you just need to update whole cell. It's up tou you, how you'll prepare update data in your code.

SQL:

`update tablename set Value = 'A1 A2' where ID=1`